# Narrow criteria to UPDATE statement within INSERT trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, triggers

I'm biting the bullet and getting to know Triggers to support the requirements of my Application.  I've created a test trigger (on a test table), how do I add criteria so that the UPDATE statement only affects those records inserted

EDIT - I've found an example elsewhere that links to the `inserted` table and it seems to work, just want to do a sanity check with people to make sure there's nothing obviously wrong as I don't want to mess it up!

```
ALTER TRIGGER ztblTest_INSERT 
   ON  we_ci_db.dbo.ztblTest
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
UPDATE ztblTest
SET TestFieldB=we_ci_db.dbo.ztblTest.TestFieldA
WHERE TestID IN (SELECT DISTINCT TestID FROM inserted)

END
GO
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a temporary table for inserted/updated records called `inserted`. This should have the same structure as the table you are updating, so you can join to it on whatever criteria you need to (or use in a where clause, as you mention in your question).

Although not directly relevant to your question as your trigger only cares about inserts, there's also a temporary table for deleted records for use during triggers, called `deleted`.

There's some examples of using these temporary tables on this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx).